# "It got me confused" - incorrect, then why "she got him confused by.." is correct?

Tags: grammar, causative-get

I have read that "it (e.g. a situation) got me confused" is not correct. But in some books I have read sentences such as "you got him confused by...", so is it wrong, too? Or neither is?

Comment: _It got me confused_ is acceptable in informal speech, but it would be more correct to say _It made me confused_ or _It confused me._

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, for me it is difficult to tell which construction is still valid and which is not, when talking about using "get" to indicate that something caused something else. E.g. "He got it working" is I believe correct. "It got me thinking" I would say, too. Then I  cannot see why "got me confused" is different...EDIT: Ah, I guess it is because GET SB DOING STH is a construction

Comment: John, to sum it up quickly. The verb *get* takes an object and then a non finite clause as catenative complement. It is *causative* in meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> it got me confused

(where "it" is a situation) is a completely correct construct. One of the meanings of "get" is to cause something to happen.

> He got me ready

> It got me fired

> He got the computer working

Some would see it as relatively informal, but it is frequently used. You will read it in many places, including well-known and highly-crafted works. "It made me confused" would be an alternative.

> you got him confused by...

is exactly the same construct with exactly the same usage. Each is as acceptable as the other.

Note the slightly different construct

> you got him confused with someone

meaning that you mixed up "him" with "someone".

Answer (score 2):

> it got me confused.

The usage shown in your example is illustrated in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get)

*get* in this context is defined as *cause* as in "to cause something to happen, or cause someone or something to do something".

> [ + adj ] She had to get the kids ready for school.

Comment: Yes, *get* is a 'causative verb', but I don't think that's what the op is asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Erm, just don’t use that form, it appears fairly badly formed to me, much better:

> You confused him.

> The instructions shouted by the Sargeant Major confused me.

> I became confused as to the plot as the story progressed.

> Confusion abounds as someone sticks “got” in the sentence!

Alternatives, for other forms:

> I mistook her for someone else.